# Remove backslash from the string C#

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I have string in which some xml resides.

The string is:

```
string xmlRead = "<ns0:RequestedAmount xmlns:ns0=\"http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd\">  <ns0:RequestedAmount></ns0:RequestedAmount>  </ns0:RequestedAmount>" +
                         "<ns0:Response xmlns:ns0=\"http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd\">  <ns0:Response/> </ns0:Response>" +
                         "<ns0:isValid xmlns:ns0=\"http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd\">  <ns0:isValid/> </ns0:isValid>";
```

I have tried this:

```
string s=xmlRead.Replace(@"\","");
string s=xmlRead.Replace("\"","");
string s=xmlRead.Replace(@"\",string.Empty);
```

Nothing is working kindly help me out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: There aren't any backslashes in that string, that I can see. All I can see are escaped characters, e.g. `\"` which only puts a `"` into the string.

Comment: But when I am passing this string Xml.Create method it gives an exception  of Illegal characters in path and when I am passing the string without this it is working fine.

Comment: What do you mean by Xml.Create? There's no `Create` method on either `XmlDocument` nor `XDocument` classes and I'm not aware of any .NET Framework class just called `Xml`.

Comment: XmlReader.Create that would be.
Typo mistake.

Comment: [`XmlReader.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf(v=vs.110).aspx) with a single string parameter expects to be passed a *uri* for where to obtain the XML from, not a piece of XML itself.

Answer (score 8):

Those backslashes won't actually appear in the final string. They are just escape sequences for the quotes `""`.

[MSDN Escape Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

My guess is that you're viewing the string in the debugger which will still show them as unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code this will help you.

```
    string x=@"ABCD\EFG";
    string y=x.Replace(@"\","");
```

Comment: Explain how that is different to the first code sample the OP provided. Did you read the question?

Comment: I just added @ in string

Comment: string xmlRead = @"<ns0:RequestedAmount xmlns:ns0=\"http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd\">  <ns0:RequestedAmount></ns0:RequestedAmount>  </ns0:RequestedAmount>" +
                         "<ns0:Response xmlns:ns0=\"http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd\">  <ns0:Response/> </ns0:Response>" +
                         "<ns0:isValid xmlns:ns0=\"http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd\">  <ns0:isValid/> </ns0:isValid>";